# Strange sorting behavior

Tags: java

```
int[] a = new int[] {7,2,1,10,8,9};
int[] b = a;
Arrays.sort(b);
```

Why do both arrays get sorted after the sort-operation on b. Shouldn't be only b get sorted?

Comment: There is no _both arrays_, because there is only 1 array with two references to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it is only one array. "a" and "b" are only references to the same array.

If you would use the clone method to copy the values, then a and b would be different arrays and only b would be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Because `a` and `b` are references to the same array. When you do

```
int[] b = a;
```

you're not making a copy of your array, you're just copying a reference to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Both `b` and `a` point to the same array object. So they both are same array.

Answer (score 0):

Because assigning a to b only assigns reference to the array. There is only one array in memory, so altering it alters it wherever you access it from.